# How to get factorial with a for loop?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I only get by by self-studying please be kind. So I would like to ask, without using math factorial(), is how to answer this example:

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for i in ___:
        __
    return result

print(factorial(4)) # should return 24
print(factorial(5)) # should return 120
```

So my answer is like this and what I keep getting is this:

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        result *= n
    return result

print(factorial(4)) # should return 24 but I get 16
print(factorial(5)) # should return 120 but I get 25
```

Hopefully someone is kind enough to enlighten me how to get this example properly with explanations.

Comment: Why `*= n`? It should be `*= i`

Comment: Why should it be i?

Comment: But your code *doesn't* give 25 (which is 5^2) for input 5, it gives 3125 (which is 5^5). Similar remarks apply to 4. Just trace through a run by hand to see what your code is doing.

Comment: @Duwi because that is the definition of factorial... do the math on a piece of paper

Comment: But I do get 16 and 25 though... which is what I don't understand

Comment: No, you don't get 16 and 25 when you evaluate `factorial(4)` and `factorial(5)` using the definition of `factorial` that you provide. You get 256 and 3125. I think that the code that you are running has an indentation which is different than the code that you posted. My guess it that the `return` in the code that you actually run is in the loop rather than after the loop (though not even that would explain the 16 and 25).

Comment: @DeepSpace I know what the factorial for the two numbers I just don't know how to do them in code. I tried to change the part you said and I got 5 and 6 respectively.

Comment: Anyway, I reset the block that's why I was missing range, hence the problem. I got it now though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very nearly there.
Instead of `result *= n` it should be `result *= i`

So, your code could look something like this.

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range (1, n+1):
        result *= i
    return result
```

Explanation:

The factorial of a number is simply to multiply all whole numbers starting with n down to 1. If you were to run:

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(i)
```

You would see (if n is 5):

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Since the factorial of 5 is `5*4*3*2*1`, we can take this logic and apply it to our code. Remember the values of i, printed out above. To see this in practice, add this below `result *= i`:

```
print(f'result *= {i}: {result}')
```

and check the console. Always use print statements to debug - it will greatly help your understanding of the function in doing so.

Comment: Thank you for this! I understand it now! Have a great day!

Comment: No problem, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

#Try the following code:

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for n in range(n):
        result = result*(n+1)
    return result

print(factorial(4)) 
print(factorial(5))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Bro your logic for factorial is wrong

You write

```
          for i in range(1, n+1):
                 result *= n     
          return result
```

There should be iterator insted of number
You should try this

```
       for i in range(1, n+1):
              result *= i
       return result
```